# unable to restart iptables from ansible ( Interactive authentication required)

Tags: ansible, iptables, centos7

How to restart iptables service from Ansible (in order to reload config file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`)

I have handler `restart iptables` defined as

```
service: name=iptables enabled=yes state=restarted
```

But it produces following error message:

> fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true,
>   "msg": "Failed to stop iptables.service: Interactive authentication
>   required.\n Failed to start iptables.service: Interactive
>   authentication required.\n"}

I am working with `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`

Comment: Are you running your task as sudo?

Comment: No, I was not using sudo. Adding become: yes resolved the problem. I wonder why error message is misleading. Usually missing sudo caused error message like 'Permission denied'.

Comment: If you run `systemctl restart iptables` (or equivalent if you aren't using systemd) as a non privileged user on the box directly you'll notice that you get a sudo/gksudo prompt. This is what Ansible is detecting and erroring on.

Comment: Weirdly enough the login goes to root account and still you need the become.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was not running my handler command as root. If handler contains  `become: yes` then handler works fine.

```
- name: restart iptables
  become: yes
  service: name=iptables enabled=yes state=restarted
```

Another way of refreshing iptables configuration, without restarting it is

```
- name: reload iptables
  become: yes
  shell: iptables-restore <  /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Comment: I suffered this problem in a handler. My role includes `become: yes` in the tasks/main.yml. For the handlers, I added the become statement to the handlers that needed them.